# About the behavior of inheritance by delegation

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

The model `product.product` inherits from `product.template` by delegation. As far as I knew, any field in `product.template` was available in `product.product`, even the ones added to `product.template` by standard inheritance. But not methods. Besides, any field added to `product.product` was not available in `product.template` as the relation did not work the other way round. By now, am I right?

After this introduction, this is the example of the behavior I cannot understand very well:

I have inherited from `product.template` (standard inheritance) to add the next fields:

```
uom_category_id = fields.Many2one(
    comodel_name='product.uom.categ',
    related='uom_id.category_id',
    string='UoM Category',
)
uom_id2 = fields.Many2one(
    comodel_name='product.uom',
    string='2nd UoM',
    domain="[('category_id', '=', uom_category_id)]",
)
```

Then I added both fields to the view `product_template_form_view` (primary view of `product.template` model). They work OK. However, if I open the `product.product` form view, both fields have been added but the domain does not work. To make the domain work, I have to add the field `uom_category_id` to `product.product` model.

I wonder if non-stored fields are not inherited by delegation, but if this field did not exist in `product.product` model, how could the view show it with no errors?

Comment: Seems to be a bug. There were some bugs related to "related" fields IIRC. Do you get PSQL errors while using non-stored related delegated fields, if so which? :D